# How can I retrieve Unicode characters from IMAP in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, imap

I'm trying to parse an email that is partially written in English and partially written in Japanese using PHP. Here's the code I have so far:

```
if ($mbox = imap_open($mailbox, $username, $password)) {

    $inbox = imap_check($mbox);
    $total = (int) $inbox->Nmsgs;
    $min = max(1, $total - 10);

    // fetch 10 most recent emails
    if ($total > 0 && ($emails = imap_fetch_overview($mbox, "{$min}:{$total}"))) {

        foreach ($emails as $email) {

            $body = imap_body($mbox, $email->uid, FT_UID);

            // for testing purposes
            echo $body;

            // parsing logic here

        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see I'm just echoing out the plaintext body of the email, just to test things, and here's part of the echoed response I get when I run this script:

> Your Japanese word of the day is: ç”·ã®å­

However, the following is what I *should* see in place of that, based on what's actually in the email:

> Your Japanese word of the day is: 男の子

So clearly something's being lost in translation (pun intended). I'm using some simple string manipulation to try and parse the Japanese characters, and then insert them into a MySQL database. However, it's currently inserting those gobbledygook characters instead. What am I missing?

Edit: I'm using PHP version 5.4.45

Comment: Where do you `echo` it? What is the encoding of the place you're echoing it to?

Comment: Just to my browser window

Comment: And what is the encoding for it?

Comment: The encoding is UTF-8

Comment: I believe it's not. How can you tell it is utf-8? I copied `男の子` and with a single byte encodings I get the very same wrong output you have.

Comment: Because if I click "Show Original" in Gmail to view the source, right before the section starts it says `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Gmail's mail encoding has nothing to do with the browser window encoding you're `echo`ing it to. If it's chrome check settings -> more tools -> encoding.

Comment: Even so, you're kind of missing the point. As I stated in the question, I don't really need to echo it; I'm just doing that to test things. I'm really trying to extract that part of the string and insert it into a MySQL query. However this too is inserting the wrong characters, which would lead me to believe that PHP retrieves the string from IMAP the wrong way to begin with.

Comment: So, your data is correct. "PHP retrieves the string from IMAP the wrong way to begin with." --- it retrieves it exactly right, you've just messed with encodings.

Comment: No, that's not true. I haven't altered the string in any way (besides simply doing substrings) before inserting into MySQL; however it's wrong there. A simple test if you don't believe me would be to send yourself an email with the Japanese characters in it, retrieve it using IMAP, and see what you get. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Well, the thing is: you don't understand what encoding is and how to deal with them properly. No wondering you may have messed with them somewhere (like - with your code that inserts into mysql). The fact: `ç”·ã®å­` (`0xE7 0x94 0xB7 0xE3 0x81 0xAE 0xE5 0xAD 0x90`) is the same as `男の子` if output with a single byte encoding. Anyway, if you don't believe me - have fun guessing and blaming something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not really sure how to get this working in PHP 5. I decided to try upgrading my server to PHP 7 and suddenly all of the code just started working.